# Intellisense suddenly slowed down? VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I haven't used VS2019 for the past few days. I opened it up today and Intellisense has drastically slowed down. I mean it's not awfully slow but takes 2-3 seconds while the results showed almost immediately a few days ago.

Is there a chance I installed something on my PC that slows Intellisense down? It does sound irrelevant to me but it's the only change that happened in these last days. I was studying neural networks and I installed a bunch of programms like PyCharm, Cuda, Anaconda and a lot of Python libraries for neural networks like Tensorflow. One of these even installed Nsight for VS I think.

Comment: Since you have a workaround about your issue, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues. Thanks:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah - I debugged it just a bit further. Remove NSightVSE and it speeds right back up. You can leave Cuda 11.1 SDK intact. Thank goodness.

Comment: FYI, there's a [v2020.2.1 update available](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/visual-studio-2019-became-too-slow-after-installing-cuda-11-1/155952/25) for VSE that resolves this problem.  Just tested it, and VS is back to its normal self.

Comment: A lot of us didn't make the connection to a CUDA install, especially if we're doing CUDA work outside of visual studio and only days or weeks later come back to visual studio for completely unrelated development.  Glad you shared the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a lot of people had the same issue recently. The problem is with CUDA version 11.1 and NsightVSE 2020.2. I uninstalled both and Intellisense is back to normal. From what I read, it should be fine with CUDA 11.0.3 and NsightVSE 2020.1. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: will you please PM me if you figure it out. I'm already sick of this...